# WKExtension.shared().delegate = self now shows Cannot assign to property: 'delegate' is a get-only property

Tags: swift, watchkit, xcode11

WatchOS code that used to work for background tasks requires the `WKExtention.shared().delegate` to be set to `self`, but now displays an error saying:

> Cannot assign to property: 'delegate' is a get-only property

If I remove that line, I don't get updates when background tasks are triggered as I used to be able to receive before.

I have looked up and down StackOverflow and Google and Apple documentation and I can't find an answer. Why that line now shows an error when it used to work just fine.

Make a new WatchKit App and on the `InterfaceControllerVC.swift`
add `WKExtensionDelegate` to the class and:

```swift
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
      super.awake(withContext: context)

      WKExtension.shared().delegate = self
   }
```

The line:

```swift
    WKExtension.shared().delegate = self
```

is marked red and shows error as:

> Cannot assign to property: 'delegate' is a get-only property

Answer (score 11):

Not a lot of documentation on how to do this with modern SwiftUI Apps, the Info.plist approach doesn't seem to work anymore. Maybe this will help others to solve this a bit quicker: Use `WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor`, similar to `UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`.

```
@main
struct WatchApp: App  {

@WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var extensionDelegate

@SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
       
...

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Spent hours chasing this down. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The delegate is automatically assigned by the system as it is described here.

[Apple Doc WKExtensionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate)

Setting your delegate object by doing the followings:

1. Create a class with name *Your_Class_ExtensionDelegate* and implements the protocol `WKExtensionDelegate`.
2. Make sure the value of `WKExtensionDelegateClassName` in `Info.plist` in WatchKit Extension is `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).Your_Class_ExtensionDelegate` (Module name is necessary for Swift projects.)